# Gradle, SpringBoot, MavenPublish - Publication only contains dependencies and/or constraints without a version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, maven-publish

I'm using maven-publish plugin in Gradle to publish my Spring Boot application jar. I run the usual task: `./gradlew artifactorypublish`. However, the following error appeared, which I couldn't understand the meaning of:

```
> Task :assembleArtifact
> Task :application-jar:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :application-jar:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :application-jar:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :application-jar:jar SKIPPED
> Task :generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication'.
> Invalid publication 'mavenJava':
    - Publication only contains dependencies and/or constraints without a version. You need to add minimal version information, publish resolved versions (https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:resolved_dependencies) or reference a platform (https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/platforms.html)
```

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication){
            components.java
        }
    }
}

...
```

Versions:
Gradle 6.1
Spring Boot 2.2.6 (mostly generated from Spring Boot Initializr)

Answer (score 15):

The problem that you're facing is actually the desired behavior because of the change - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/11388 that came along with Gradle 6.0.1

The thing is that Gradle requires you to provide a proper version of dependencies so as to disallow users from publishing an invalid Gradle Module Metadata. The discussions on the issues below will help you to get a deeper insight into this

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11862

https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/262

Now, in your case, there are two solutions that you can choose from

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication){
            // bootJar is the default build task configured by Spring Boot
            artifact bootJar
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information on the second option can be found on this link - https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/publishing_maven.html

Comment: FYI `artifact bootJar` skips the generation of a .module metadata for me and, looking at the source code of *DefaultMavenPublication.java*, it always will. @Isank can you elaborate a bit more on the solution using `versionMapping`. Your links to sources are brilliant but leave me asking how one would get to the solution, rather than how the solution works. E.g. where do I find info on the strings *java-api* and *java-runtime*?

Answer (score 9):

Extend the answer by @Nakamura, If you make a project to be Springboot Library and need to set:

```
bootJar {
    enabled=false
}

jar {
    enabled=true
}
```

You can set :

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication){
            // jar is the default build task configured by Spring Boot if bootJar=false
            artifact jar
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After messing around for a while, I found the solution:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication){
            // bootJar is the default build task configured by Spring Boot
            artifact bootJar
        }
    }
}
```

#### Detailed Explanation

This is because `components.java` is configured for default java plugin task: `jar` or `war`. However for Spring Boot, after applying plugin `org.springframework.boot`, the default task become `bootJar` or `bootWar`.

(For your reference) From Spring Boot doc:

> Executable jars can be built using the `bootJar` task. The task is automatically created when the `java` plugin is applied and is an instance of `BootJar`. The `assemble` task is automatically configured to depend upon the `bootJar` task so running `assemble` (or `build`) will also run the `bootJar` task.

Therefore, the artifact could not be correctly identified by `components.java`. We should point to `bootJar` or `bootWar` instead.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#publishing-your-application-maven-publish